# Allow a business user to upload data from csv to a Google Big Query table

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am preparing a tableau dashboard that reads data from certain tables. One of the tables has data that is manually added on an ad-hoc basis. The data comes from the business side. Is there a way to allow the business user to upload the csv to the big query table without having them to do anything too technical?

Comment: If the user can upload csv to google drive, then using this approach https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive you can create persistent tables in big query.

Comment: Thanks for responding @BihagKashikar. But we need to load the data in an adhoc manner, over multiple times. We need to track when the data was loaded and what changed as an effect. Maintaining all this in a sheet would be cumbersome in the long run. Do you know of any other ways? Is there an option wherein the user can upload the CSV and press a button and a service runs to upload the data into Big Query?

Comment: Hi @AntonySamuelB you can load CSV data directly into [bigquery table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#console).

Comment: Thanks for responding @kiranmathew. Unfortunately the business user is not proficient with big query and I am sort of acting as  a middle man right now by getting the csv and inserting into an existing table using a python script. I am trying to automate away my role in this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @AntonySamuelB, I have posted a solution. I am not sure whether it meets all your requirements. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can consider below methods:

**1  Using Cloud Storage transfers:**

In this method,first you need to submit a csv  file to the cloud storage.Then you can set up a Cloud Storage transfer.This transfer service for cloud storage allows you to schedule recurring data loads from Cloud Storage to BigQuery.For more information you follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#console). But keep in mind that this service has some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#setting_up_a_cloud_storage_transfer).

**2 Automate a Python script on Google Cloud.**

There are different ways to automate a python script on google cloud. In your case,you can consider using a cloud function with cloud schedular to run your python code automatically.First you need to create a cloud function to run your code. Then you can use a cloud schedular to trigger your function automatically.In a more secure way you can use trigger cloud function indirectly by using pubsub. For more information you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub).

Answer (score 1):

There's not currently a user friendly way to import straight to an existing big query table from a csv. You could package your python script into a small application that allows the business user to select a file and then runs your python script to upload the csv to BQ.
I've had to do a similar solution.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Chris Ewart. Can you provide a high level overview of the app that was used?